# Creating custom dictionary for use within an addon when dictionary items are created from actions within 1 class, so they can be used in another class

Tags: python, rigging, interface

I've been working on an addon for my own personal use to streamline my work possesses while augmenting rigs etc..

My general work process is to create a menu with buttons to breakup larger tasks into steps, such as selecting and duplicating large selections of a rig for renaming later on, so as to allow for check points.

The problem I'm running into is that in my understanding if I create a custom variable **within** a class that said custom variable only remains valid for use within the **given class** and needs to be recreated in any **other** parent or sibling level class the variable is to be used. **How do I shunt my created variables into a "public access" dictionary at the parent or sibling level so I can use the same custom variables created in one class (ClassB) within another class (ClassC) without re-contextualizing the initially created variable?**

For instance:

*One of my classes selects all the main finger control bones and the main thumb control bones on both sides of the body (button A runs ClassA).*  ---  I break the code there to allow for any needed manual correction to the selection due to any unforeseen changes, such as added or removed fingers or feathers in future rigs.

*Then I use another class (ClassB) to create a custom variable for the selected bones (I.E.: `bpy.obj.pose.bones.selected_bones = nameOriginals`)*

Now that only the original desired bones have been added to the variable, *I press the next button in my menu (ClassC) and toggle into edit mode and duplicate the selected bones.* Since the creation of the duplicates automatically deselects the original bones while having all the duplicated bones selected in isolation, *I now toggle to pose mode & create a custom variable to select only these bones again later. (I.E.: `bpy.obj.pose.bones.selected_bones = nameDupliMCH`) Using this custom variable I rename the duplicated bones removing the .001 etc. and replacing it with my desired suffix. and move nameDulpiMCH to the MCH bone layer.*

Finally after confirming that all worked, *I need to re-parent the Duplicate bones to their corresponding Originals (ClassD). To do that I need to be able to select "nameOriginals" as active.* However, with nameOriginals being only named/available in ClassB and re-selection to recreate the variable now too complicated due to the duplicates, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: can you keep an instance of ClassB around so it's still reachable from ClassD?  Then you could create a list of "nameOriginals" in the ClassB instance and then query it in ClassD.  Worst case you could make "nameOriginals" a class attribute I suppose.

Comment: It sounds like you could be onto something @MartyFouts, However at the moment with my limited Blender Python coding knowledge, this is the 1st I'm hearing of instancing a code. And If I knew how running the query would seem to work. I've seen class attributes before but I didn't really know how to use them. For the record, my biggest problem in bpy is not with problem solving, but rather with the syntax and proper methods/names for methods. Any help on that front is appreciated, as without it I don't even know where to look.